eslint to write console always in one line
for personal reasons I want console.(log|error|...) always to be written in one line.
is there a eslint rule for that which is tested and works?
my approach below introduces some arbitrary syntax problems
module.exports = {
  meta: {
    fixable: 'code',
  },
  create(context) {
    return {
      CallExpression(node) {
        if (
          node.callee.object &&
          node.callee.object.name === 'console' &&
          node.callee.property
        ) {
          const sourceCode = context.getSourceCode()
          const text = sourceCode.getText(node)

          // Check if there are comments inside the console statement
          const comments = sourceCode.getCommentsInside(node)

          if (text.includes('\n')) {
            if (comments.length > 0) {
              // Raise a warning if there are comments inside
              context.report({
                node,
                message:
                  'console.' +
                  node.callee.property.name +
                  ' contains comments and should be checked manually',
              })
            } else {
              // Fix the text if there are no comments
              context.report({
                node,
                message:
                  'console.' +
                  node.callee.property.name +
                  ' should be in one line',
                fix(fixer) {
                  const fixedText = text.replace(/\n/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
                  return fixer.replaceText(node, fixedText)
                },
              })
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
}



It would be helpful to include examples of what you want to be valid and what you want to avoid.

turns out that the interference with other rules was leading to the mess - the rule above actually works when called by itself (or in a dedicated .eslintrc-custom conf-file )
npx eslint  --fix --rule 'custom-eslint-rules/console-log-fix: ["error"]' . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx


folder structure:

eslint
|- rules
 |- console-log-fix.js 
\ index.js

index.js

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const rulesDir = path.join(__dirname, 'rules')
const ruleFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(rulesDir)
  .filter(file => file !== 'index.js' && !file.endsWith('test.js'))

const rules = Object.fromEntries(
  ruleFiles.map(file => [
    path.basename(file, '.js'),
    require(path.join(rulesDir, file)),
  ])
)

module.exports = { rules }


